# Adding two numbers that were declared as char type in java how it is posible?

Tags: java, addition

If the single quotes are removed in the declaration it is showing 11

```
class Sample
{
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
         char v1='5';
         char v2='6';
         System.out.println(v1 + v2);
    }
}
```

Output:
        107

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, a `char` is a [16-bit, unsigned integral type.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) When used in arithmetic operations, [they are "promoted"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) to `int` operands with the same value.

The Unicode character `'5'` has a value of 53, and `'6'` has a value of 54. Add them together, and you have 107.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the numeric equivalent of a `char` using `Character.getNumericValue(char)`:

```
class Sample
{
  public static void main(String ar[])
  {
    char v1='5';
    char v2='6';
    int i1 = Character.getNumericValue(v1);
    int i2 = Character.getNumericValue(v2);
    System.out.println(i1 + i2);
  }
}
```

The function maps chars like `'5'` to numbers like `5`.

Fun fact: it also works with other numbering systems like `'๕'`, the Thai number 5.